# AndroidAnnotations minimum API supported

Tags: android-annotations

I would like to know the minimum Android API level AndroidAnnoatations supports ? I could not find any info on their website .

regards,
Felix T

Answer (score 1):

I think there is **NO** specific minimum Android API Level that AndroidAnnotations can work with.
Since it's a *compilation* tool, I mean it's related with the Java files and it's related not with Android API.

If you build an Android project with AndroidAnnotations, then some intermediate java files will be generated, which will be the final java file for Java compiler, and that's all. It's just used for convinience of your development. The generated `apk` file will not have information about AndroidAnnotations - it's something like a conversion tool (shorter exprssion to long complicated expression, which is not visible to you).

I think that you can use AndroidAnnotation from Android API Level 1.
Maybe some of the annotations cannot be used in Android API 1 project, but even if such case happens, just removing *only that specific annotation* in your .java file will make it work.